# Java Steam Issue in Spring Boot -> Not Calculate total value (Size and Pagination Issue)

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I have a problem to calculate order report with the usage of Java Stream in my Spring Boot example.

For example, I have 21 orders.

When I send a request shown below,

```
{
  "page": 0,
  "size": 22
}
```

I got this result shown below

```
{
    "response": {
        "content": [
            {
                "month": "SEPTEMBER",
                "year": 2023,
                "totalOrderCount": 21,
                "totalBookCount": 21,
                "totalPrice": 2079.00
            }
        ],
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 22,
        "totalPageCount": 1,
        "totalElementCount": 1
    },
    "isSuccess": true,
    "httpStatus": "OK",
    "time": "2023-09-18T23:12:26.3410251"
}
```

When I send a request this,

```
{
  "page": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

I get this response message shown below

```
{
    "response": {
        "content": [
            {
                "month": "SEPTEMBER",
                "year": 2023,
                "totalOrderCount": 10,
                "totalBookCount": 10,
                "totalPrice": 990.00
            }
        ],
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "totalPageCount": 3,
        "totalElementCount": 21
    },
    "isSuccess": true,
    "httpStatus": "OK",
    "time": "2023-09-18T23:13:27.1144251"
}
```

Here is my **expected** result shown below

```
{
        "response": {
            "content": [
                {
                    "month": "SEPTEMBER",
                    "year": 2023,
                    "totalOrderCount": 21,
                    "totalBookCount": 21,
                    "totalPrice": 990.00
                }
            ],
            "pageNumber": 0,
            "pageSize": 10,
            "totalPageCount": 3,
            "totalElementCount": 21
        },
        "isSuccess": true,
        "httpStatus": "OK",
        "time": "2023-09-18T23:13:27.1144251"
    }
```

or

```
{
        "response": {
            "content": [
                {
                    "month": "SEPTEMBER",
                    "year": 2023,
                    "totalOrderCount": 21,
                    "totalBookCount": 21,
                    "totalPrice": 2079.00
                }
            ],
            "pageNumber": 0,
            "pageSize": 22,
            "totalPageCount": 1,
            "totalElementCount": 21
        },
        "isSuccess": true,
        "httpStatus": "OK",
        "time": "2023-09-18T23:12:26.3410251"
    }
```

As you can see, `order size < size` -> `totalOrderCount` and `totalBookCount` would be wrong value and `order size > size` -> totalElementCount would be wrong value.

How can I fix it?

All these processes can be done from StatisticsController shown below.

```
public class StatisticsController {

    private final StatisticsService statisticsService;

    private final Identity identity;

    @GetMapping("/{customerId}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_CUSTOMER')")
    public CustomResponse<CustomPageResponse<OrderReportResponse>> getOrderStatisticsByCustomer(
            @PathVariable Long customerId,
            @RequestBody PaginationRequest paginationRequest
    ) {

        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = identity.getCustomUserDetails();

        if ((customUserDetails.getId().equals(customerId) &&
                customUserDetails.getUser().getRole().equals(Role.ROLE_CUSTOMER)
        ) || customUserDetails.getUser().getRole().equals(Role.ROLE_ADMIN)
        ) {
            Page<OrderReportDTO> orderReportDtosByCustomer = statisticsService.getOrderStatisticsByCustomer(customerId, paginationRequest);
            CustomPageResponse<OrderReportResponse> orderReportResponse = OrderReportMapper.toOrderReportResponseList(orderReportDtosByCustomer);
            return CustomResponse.ok(orderReportResponse);
        }

        throw new AccessDeniedException("You cannot access order statistics");
    }

    @GetMapping("/allstatistics")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public CustomResponse<CustomPageResponse<OrderReportResponse>> getOrderStatistics(@RequestBody PaginationRequest paginationRequest) {

        Page<OrderReportDTO> orderReportAllDtos = statisticsService.getOrderStatistics(paginationRequest);
        CustomPageResponse<OrderReportResponse> orderReportResponse = OrderReportMapper.toOrderReportResponseList(orderReportAllDtos);
        return CustomResponse.ok(orderReportResponse);

    }

}
```

Here is the Java Stream method to calculate statistics for orders.

```
private Page<OrderReportDTO> calculateTotalOrderCountByMonth(Page<Order> customerOrders) {

        Map<String, List<Order>> ordersByMonthYear = customerOrders.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        order -> order.getCreatedAt().getYear() + "-" + order.getCreatedAt().getMonth()
                ));

        List<OrderReportDTO> reportDTOs = ordersByMonthYear.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> {
                    String monthYearKey = entry.getKey();
                    List<Order> ordersForMonthYear = entry.getValue();
                    int totalOrderCount = ordersForMonthYear.size();

                    int totalBookCount = ordersForMonthYear.stream()
                            .mapToInt(order -> order.getOrderItems().size())
                            .sum();

                    BigDecimal totalPrice = ordersForMonthYear.stream()
                            .flatMap(order -> order.getOrderItems().stream())
                            .map(orderItem -> orderItem.getBook().getPrice())
                            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

                    // Splitting the monthYearKey to extract month and year
                    String[] parts = monthYearKey.split("-");
                    String month = parts[1];
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);

                    return new OrderReportDTO(month, year, totalOrderCount, totalBookCount, totalPrice);
                })
                .toList();

        return new PageImpl<>(reportDTOs, customerOrders.getPageable(), customerOrders.getTotalElements());
    }
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery)

Comment: Can you please also share your _expected_ response, what exactly is different and why it should be the expected response as opposed to the actual response? Can you please also include the code of `StatisticsService#getOrderStatistics`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the java stream part. However there is an issue with the way the data is being aggregated.

If the table orders contains the following:

```
id      created_at
1       2023-01-01
2       2023-01-15
3       2023-01-18
4       2023-01-19
```

Doing a `findAll` with page size `2` and starting with page `0` will only return the first two records.

And the report is calculated based on the 2 records only, which is wrong. Since records with id `3` and `4` also are part of January.

I think it is best to aggregate the data using JPQL and project the result in a DTO as such:

```
// in OrderRepository
@Query("select " +
        "new com.example.demo.dto.OrderReportDTO(" +
            "month(o.createdAt), " +
            "year(o.createdAt)," +
            "count(o.orderItems)," +
            "count(items), " +
            "sum(items.book.price)" +
        ") " +
        "from Order o " +
        "inner join o.orderItems items " +
        "group by " +
            "month(o.createdAt), " +
            "year(o.createdAt)")
Page<OrderReportDTO> getReports(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: You will need to do some investigation and solve the issue. The query provided has not been tested. I wrote it as an example to show you how the data aggregation and dto projection can be done.

Comment: But as far for `I have a problem to calculate order report with the usage of Java Stream`, there is no java stream issue in the code and the query I provided is an addition 